# Package autonum breaks all references when used with thm-restate

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices, cleveref, autonum

I have the following LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thm-restate, autonum}
\newtheorem{lem}{lemma}
\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}[Embedding lemma]{lem}{embedding}
   \label{lem:embedding}
   \begin{align}...\end{align}
\end{restatable}
\embedding*

\section{Bla bla}\label{sec:test}\ref{sec:test}

\end{document}
```

Compiling it gives the warnings:

```
Package remreset Warning: The remreset package is obsolete:
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:test' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

If I remove `autonum` the problems goes away.
Is this a known issue?

Comment: Hey and welcome. It would be much easier to help you if you would add a bit more to your code so that we can try to reproduce the issue. If you don't to this, the only ones able to help you will be those who know whether or not it's a known bug. If the issue is something else, noone will be able to help you

Comment: @sheß Thank you for the kind welcome. I have added a small working example now.

Comment: Which packages versions are you using? On TeXLive 2018 frozen, I get an amsmath must be loaded before cleverref error, which goes away if I load amsmath along with thmtools

Comment: With your example I only get problems with the figure ref, the cref on the lemma works fine. Looking at the aux file, the fig: label does not seem to be written to it

Comment: @daleif Right, I only get an error on the figure, but only if the lemma was stated before it. I run TeX Live 2018 as well. It doesn't make a difference whether I import amsmath or not.

Comment: You need amsmath for align (no idea which of the packages autoloads it at begin document). I don't use either autonum or cleveref so cannot debug more.

Comment: Turns out that the error also happens without cleverref and figures. It just breaks all references.