# Autonum and restatable incompatible

Tags: cross-referencing, incompatibility, thmtools, autonum

I'm using the autonum package. If I want to restate a lemma using thm-restate package, which includes an align environment, all lemmas after that restate cannot be referenced to. Any workarounds? I'd like to keep the autonum package.

This question is similar to [Package autonum breaks all references when used with thm-restate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482088/package-autonum-breaks-all-references-when-used-with-thm-restate), but no answer was given there.

See MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}


\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}


This is the lemma to restate
\begin{restatable}{lemma}{lemmaToRestate}
This lemma has an align environment
\begin{align}
    p \in P
\end{align}
\end{restatable}

I restate it now:
\lemmaToRestate*

Then a new lemma, which cannot be referred to, e.g., \ref{newlemma}
\begin{lemma}
\label{newlemma}
    my new lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I also want to use this in combination with the cleverref package. This seems to be incompatible with the suggested `showonlyrefs` option from mathtools, so this does not help me unfortunately. Also, I don't want to remove the autonum package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: looking at the code I would advise to avoid the use of autonum.

Comment: You can try the `showonlyrefs` option of mathtools as an alternative to autonum

Comment: Imho your chance to get an answer or a fix for mathtools is higher than with autonum. mathtools is still actively maintained.  And instead of cleveref you could look at zref-clever which is maintained too.