# Defining control sequence \blx@noerroretextools for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

It seems like the biblatex interface changed slightly, and it now asks that a control sequence is defined to toggle a certain behaviour rather than an option passed to the package.

```
The option 'noerroretextools' is deprecated.
(biblatex)  Define the control sequence '\blx@noerroretextools'
(biblatex)  before loading biblatex instead.
```

This is probably blindgly obvious, but how do I define said control sequence? Seems like the `@` character is causing me trouble if I try just using `\newcommand`.

Comment: Maybe try something like `\makeatletter\newcommand{\blx@noerroretextools}{}\makeatother`. If this does not help, please provide a test file.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: why do you use that option at all? It is only there as a work around for the etextools package which you shouldn't use anyway.

Comment: To use the autonum package. If you have a suggestion for a different package that fills a similar niche and doesn't require workarounds, I'm all ears.

Comment: One of the reasons why I wouldn't use autonum https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703076/autonum-and-restatable-incompatible#comment1749015_703076

Comment: I still have the same question: if not autonum, how else to handle equation numbering? Surely not manually?

Comment: as mentioned in the comments I linked to: use mathtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown error can be avoided by defining the command `\blx@noerroretextools` before loading `biblatex` and not passing the `noerroretextools` option to `biblatex`.

So instead of loading `biblatex` as follows

```
\usepackage[noerroretextools]{biblatex}
```

you could try

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blx@noerroretextools}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

as suggested by [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705429/defining-control-sequence-blxnoerroretextools-for-biblatex?noredirect=1#comment1753698_705429).

But if you use this trick, you absolutely need to make sure that `etextools` does not overwrite any of the `etoolbox` commands that `biblatex` needs. You can find some discussions over at [Biblatex and newtxmath are not working together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431965/35864), https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/669. The code you are using at the moment may already do that, but there is no way of knowing if this is the case. That's why `biblatex` makes it hard for you to just load `etextools`: Unless you (or the code you load) actively make sure to restore the required `etoolbox` definitions, things will break with random error messages.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to get this off the unanswered list!